# Java 8 streams. How to aggregate BigDecimal totals per enumerated type into a custom bean

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, java-stream

Its hard to word the question. Heres my code snippet:

```
Map<PassType, PassTypeRate> ratesPerType = new HashMap<>();

entries.stream().forEach((entry) -> {
    if (!ratesPerType.containsKey(entry.getPassType())) {
        ratesPerType.put(entry.getPassType(), new PassTypeRate(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal.ZERO));
    }

    if (AgeType.ADULT.equals(entry.getAgeType())) {
        PassTypeRate passTypeRate = ratesPerType.get(entry.getPassType());
        passTypeRate.setAdultRate(passTypeRate.getAdultRate().add(entry.getRate()));
    }
    if (AgeType.CHILD.equals(entry.getAgeType())) {
        PassTypeRate passTypeRate = ratesPerType.get(entry.getPassType());
        passTypeRate.setChildRate(passTypeRate.getChildRate().add(entry.getRate()));
    }
});
```

So `entries` is a list of beans that holds an ageType, passType and rate. I need to aggregate the total rates per 'ageType' and 'passType'.

The PassTypeRate bean holds an aggregated total of rate for adult or child per 'PassType'.

My basic question is....is it possible at all to rewrite the above snippet using Java 8 Collectors or similar? I can't figure it out.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, looks like a good candidate to implement with `Collectors.toMap`. Take a look at below implementation (I used lombok (https://projectlombok.org/) to make it more readable):

```java
    Map<PassType, PassTypeRate> group(List<DataEntry> entries) {
        return entries.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        DataEntry::getPassType,
                        entry -> PassTypeRate.builder()
                                .adultRate(entry.getAgeType() == ADULT ? entry.getRate() : BigDecimal.ZERO)
                                .childRate(entry.getAgeType() == CHILD ? entry.getRate() : BigDecimal.ZERO)
                                .build(),
                        (rate1, rate2) -> PassTypeRate.builder()
                                .childRate(rate1.getChildRate().add(rate2.getChildRate()))
                                .adultRate(rate1.getAdultRate().add(rate2.getAdultRate()))
                                .build()
                ));
    }
```

And short explanation:

- Firstly, we need to define `PassType` as a map key
- Secondly, we need to map our `DataEntry` to single `PassTypeRate` objects. If this is `Adult` entry, then new `PassTypeRate` has to have a value in `adultRate` field and zero in `childRate`. And vice versa.
- But some entries may have the same `PassType`! So we need to define third function - the merge function. How do we merge `PassTypeRate` objects? By adding proper rates. Merge function returns new `PassTypeRate` as a result of addition of two `PassTypeRate` objects.

I've also prepared some test case to verify if solution works - and seems it works :) Test case below:

```java
public class RateGroupingTest {

    private RateGrouping subject = new RateGrouping();

    @Test
    public void groups() {
        //given
        List<DataEntry> entries = List.of(
                new DataEntry(ADULT, X, new BigDecimal("3")),
                new DataEntry(ADULT, Y, new BigDecimal("5")),
                new DataEntry(ADULT, Z, new BigDecimal("7")),
                new DataEntry(CHILD, X, new BigDecimal("11")),
                new DataEntry(CHILD, Y, new BigDecimal("13")),
                new DataEntry(CHILD, Z, new BigDecimal("17")),

                new DataEntry(ADULT, X, new BigDecimal("13")),
                new DataEntry(ADULT, Y, new BigDecimal("25")),
                new DataEntry(ADULT, Z, new BigDecimal("37")),
                new DataEntry(CHILD, X, new BigDecimal("411")),
                new DataEntry(CHILD, Y, new BigDecimal("513")),
                new DataEntry(CHILD, Z, new BigDecimal("617"))
        );

        //when
        Map<PassType, PassTypeRate> actual = subject.group(entries);

        //then
        assertThat(actual.get(PassType.X))
                .isEqualTo(
                        PassTypeRate.builder()
                                .childRate(new BigDecimal("422"))
                                .adultRate(new BigDecimal("16"))
                                .build()
                );
        assertThat(actual.get(PassType.Y))
                .isEqualTo(
                        PassTypeRate.builder()
                                .childRate(new BigDecimal("526"))
                                .adultRate(new BigDecimal("30"))
                                .build()
                );
        assertThat(actual.get(PassType.Z))
                .isEqualTo(
                        PassTypeRate.builder()
                                .childRate(new BigDecimal("634"))
                                .adultRate(new BigDecimal("44"))
                                .build()
                );
    }
}
```